# Ping/SSH into Virtualbox Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, server, ssh, virtualbox

I have a legacy Ubuntu 14.04 server installed as a virtual machine, where I can succesfully ssh to, but if I try to do the same over a newly installed virtual machine with Ubuntu 20.04, it fails. The IP for the Ubuntu 14.04 VM is 192.168.56.101, and the IP I want for the Ubuntu 20.04 VM is the next IP, "192.168.56.102".

The "Host network manager" has the following configuration:

[image]

If I enable the DHCP Server, however, Ubuntu 14.04 still works fine: I have internet inside the VM, and can still ping/ssh from my local machine to the VM.

My static IP configuration (`cat /etc/network/interfaces`) from the Ubuntu 14.04 machine is the following one:

[image]

And the corresponding `ifconfig` is:

[image]

[image]

Also, I didn't need to add any port-forwarding rules and everything works fine in the Ubuntu 14.04 server. So I haven't add any port-forwarding rules to the Ubuntu 20.04 VM either.

And, on the Ubuntu 20.04 VM, it's currently the following one (although I've tried a lot of variants):

[image]

I keep the `netplan` configuration at minimum for this question because, it doesn't matter what I do, I cannot make it work. If I enable the DHCP Server on the "Host Network Manager" and just add a `dhcp4: true` line in the `netplan` configuration, I have internet within the Ubuntu 20.04 VM, without having to specify `nameservers`, `gateway4` or anything like that, but still can't ping/ssh from local to VM. If I disable the DHCP server (as I have right now), no matter which config I add, I don't even have internet. Anyway, the config I have tried is `gateway4: 192.168.58.1` with nameservers "8.8.8.8" and "8.8.4.4".

With the default configuration of `netplan`, and the DHCP server disabled or enabled in the "Host network manager", I have internet within the Ubuntu 20.04 VM. The corresponding default `netplan` config and corresponding `ifconfig` output for the Ubuntu 20.04 VM is:

```
network:
   ethernets:
      enp0s3:
         dhcp4: true
   version: 2
```

[image]

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved. I have now internet access and ping/ssh access from my local machine in the Ubuntu 20.04 VM.

My following simplest as hell `netplan` configuration in my Ubuntu 20.04 VM machine is:

```
network:
   ethernets:
      enp0s3:   
        dhcp4: true
      enp0s8:
        addresses: [192.168.56.102/24]
   version: 2
```

I guess, by parallelism, the `enp0s3` interface of my Ubuntu 20.04 VM, which IP is `10.0.2.15` (the same as my `eth0` interface in my Ubuntu 14.04 VM), is the one used for internet. So I guess it will take the NAT conection of VirtualBox to access to the internet, and the `enp0s8` (I took that name because I remember after a fresh install of the VM I saw that interface) will take the host-only interface, as `eth1` does in my Ubuntu 14.04 VM.

I didn't set any other config because I guess the DNS resolution of the second interface will take the default of the system, or will reuse the one of the interface used for internet access, the gateway will be automatically deduced from the static IP, and the `rendered` will probably be `networkd` by default, or maybe the default in servers.